# Stop DIVs wrapping around...>

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm trying to create a project control like Microsoft Project for those of you who know it.

I have one Container Div, and then two sub container as follows:

Each Sub container has lots of internal divs, for example, my first sub container has divs for:

```
- ID, 
- WBS,
- Description
- Start Date, 
- End Date,
- Resource,
- etc
```

This is a [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzt21w2k/29/) for it.

The second sub container will have the gantt chart, so one div per day for as many days as the project lasts for, could be in excess of 300 days.

The problem I have is that the sub container wrap around to the next line when they reach the right handed of the window.
How can I make it stop wrapping?

I've tried:
in the main container:

```
overflow: auto;
overflow: visible;
```

And then for the sub containers:

```
display: inline-block;
```

But as you can see in the JSFiddle, it just wraps around to the next line.
I've gone through the related posts here on Stack and have googled too but the proposed answers (mainly overflow and display) don't work for me :(

How can I make it stop wrapping?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2s3muo0u/?

Comment: yes just like that :) Thanks a lot! it works :)

Comment: actually... it works great for the first sub container but it still wraps the other containers as you can see in that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2s3muo0u/5/    do you know how I could make all 3 containers line up on just one line so I have Container 1 (column headers) + container 2 (which I will use to resize the first container left and right) + container 3 (which has all the dates for the gantt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `min-width` equal to at least `1000px` or whatever maximum amount of columns you will have

Comment: the problem I have is that the width is not fixed, as you can see I have a column called Add New Column... and on the right div (with the dates), it will be dynamic and built from a php loop which will add as many days as the project is long... so both divs have a dynamic width. this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2s3muo0u/5/    has the finished product but I want everything on one line back to back. any ideas?

Comment: Why not make the div wrapper/container scrollable? that way they can be a fixed width. The user will have to scroll anyway if more columns are added.

Comment: that's a good point... could you help with the css in the fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bryeetz/2s3muo0u/25/

i wasn't sure what your #rsh span was for, but it was causing a new line in the div

Comment: that is extremely helpful... Ive made a couple of mods to reflect the logic on the next div (gantt) so now I have them both working as I want... but do you know how I can have both divs side by side on 1 row like this: <project div><gantt div> instead of gantt under project? updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2s3muo0u/41/

Comment: I don't have time to fiddle, I will if you still have questions in a bit. But essentially, set both wrapper divs to be inline-block. That should do it

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement allows scrollable divs,then "overflow-x: auto" in stylesheet might work